# Equivalente ao wrap em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

O `jquery` tem um método chamado `wrap` que basicamente adiciona um container ao elemento desejado, mas não consigo achar o método em javascript, alguém sabe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente não encontrei em nenhum lugar uma função equivalente, onde se passa um elemento e uma string html como container, então fiz a minha própria, está funcionando perfeitamente, vou deixar aqui para referências futuras.

```js
function lastNode(el) {
  if(el.children.length) return lastNode(el.children[el.children.length-1]);
  else return el;
}

function wrap(string, el) {
  creat = document.createElement('div');
  creat.innerHTML = string;
  parent = el.parentNode;
  lastNode(creat).appendChild(el);
  parent.appendChild(creat.firstChild);
}

let string = '<div id="e3"><div id="e4"></div></div>';
let el = document.querySelector('#e5');
wrap(string , el);
```

```css
#e1 {
  border: 5px black solid;
}
#e2 {
  border: 5px orange solid;
}
#e3 {
  border: 5px purple solid;
}
#e4 {
  border: 5px green solid;
}
#e5 {
  border: 5px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="e1">
  <div id="e2">
    <div id="e5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bem, acho que talvez isso te ajude.

```
org_html = document.getElementById("containerPAI").innerHTML;
new_html = "<div id='containerFILHO'>" + org_html + "</div>";
document.getElementById("containerPAI").innerHTML = new_html;
```

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

Links de referência para estudo:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176839/how-can-i-wrap-all-elements-in-one-container-rather-than-each-element
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838104/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472754/wrap-a-around-div-without-jquery
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488322/wrap-an-element-like-wrap-function-in-jquery-with-pure-js

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mas estava procurando algo como o wrap, onde se passa o código html inteiro sem concatenação.

Answer (score 0):

Algo do tipo funcionaria:

```js
function wrapHTML (element, wrapperElement) {

  //Aqui você define seu wrapper
  let wrapper = wrapperElement || document.createElement('div');
  //Colocando um id só para evidenciar o wrapper.
  wrapper.id = 'divFilha';
  
  element.parentNode.appendChild(wrapper);
  wrapper.appendChild(element);
  
  return wrapper;
}

wrapHTML(document.getElementById('conteudoWrap'));
console.log(document.getElementById('divPai'));
```

```html
<div id="divPai">
  <input id="conteudoWrap" type="text" />
</div>
```